# How do I get "Quickly" to use Git?

Tags: application-development, git, quickly

How do I get [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) to use Git as its default version control instead of Bazaar?

Comment: Did you filed a bug somewhere on Launchpad? I would happily subscribe it if you did so! :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, in the current state of Quickly, you cannot. However it maybe possible to have Quickly extended to support this in the future, and you could report a bug.

I would caution against it though, since Quickly is not designed to use git, as it's really a tool for making it easier to use the Ubuntu related tools and environment to build Applications for Ubuntu (and possibly other Linux/UNIX systems if you choose to port the applications later). These tools would include Launchpad, Bazaar, etc.