# Ubuntu Quickly with different revision control

Tags: development, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get “Quickly” to use Git?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43716/how-do-i-get-quickly-to-use-git)

How can I configure `quickly save` to use a different revision control system like `git` or `hg`??

I really do not like `bzr`, and most probably will never use `PPA`s because I mostly do private research projects.

Comment: Closing this as it's a clear duplicate. Just to add that I'm fairly sure that nothing has changed since last year. Quickly is still tightly integrated for use with the standard Ubuntu development/distribution stack.